# Collapse view if can't fit it's intrinsic size in AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I have `UILabel` and `UIButton` inside view which can have different size, and I want label to be hidden completely if it can't fit all the content within current frame using only AutoLayout. So basically I want it to follow it's intrinsic size, and if it shrink, it should shrink straight to zero without any middle width. Desired example:

[image: example non-collapsed]
[image: desired collapsed view]

Instead, I'm having it shrinking and trying to display as much as possible:

[image]

Is it possible to do only using AutoLayout? If not, why?

I tried to add zero-width constraint on label and set it's priority to be less than compression resistance of the label, but this does not work. I thought that once Autolayout engine broke intristic size rule, mine zero-width will be followed, but it seems I'm missing something.

EDIT: I would accept to embed label in some `UIView` subclass that can check intristic sizes of subviews and do layout in code, but I'm searching for most clean solution in general.

[You can check out xib source in this gist](https://gist.github.com/ReDetection/fa16aa8fa287c2822f5b47e438660562)

Comment: Just fix the width of the button, and make the constraint between them a constant value, it will work

Comment: @Tj3n I just checked your proposal – it does not work, I still have half label onscreen. I added source code of xib, can you please make a fork with your solution and post it as answer? I might be missing something else

Comment: Your xib work as expected, I think i got wrong idea of yours, If you want it only either show full text or none (without the ...), you would have to use code to do that, use `boundingRectWithSize ` to compare with the current label size and hide the label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solutions is to embed label into custom `UIView` and during it's layout I directly check if size got smaller than intristic size:

```
@implementation AutocollapsibleView

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    UIView *subview = self.subviews.firstObject;
    if (self.bounds.size.width < subview.intrinsicContentSize.width) {
        subview.frame = CGRectZero;
    } else {
        [super layoutSubviews];
    }
}

@end
```

Fortunately it works with `IB_DESIGNABLE` marco so I instantly see result in the Interface Builder

Comment: Seems like you should call `[super layoutSubviews]` first no matter what, then adjust the frame of the subview if necessary.

Comment: @par can you please elaborate why? [Apple documentations](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) does not state this, but it does states that I can override default implementation freely. For all places like `viewDidAppear` they do state this explicitly. I find it quite strange to take time layouting frames which will be discarded then.

Comment: @par ok, it seems calling super required on iOS6. On iOS 8+ works fine without it.

Comment: The `UIView` documentation states: `The default implementation of this method does nothing on iOS 5.1 and earlier. Otherwise, the default implementation uses any constraints you have set to determine the size and position of any subviews.` -- So on iOS > 5.1 the default implementation is *not* a no-op and you *must* call `super.layoutSubviews()` to get correct layout from the base classes.  It's also a best practice in case anyone subclasses your class (since you'll want them to call your `layoutSubviews` override). You should update this answer to call it as the first line in your function.

Comment: That's correct that `layoutSubiews` should do layout so it does try to satisfy constraints. But it does not mean I _must_ call super if I do my own layout. The only thing – you have to make sure you have no conflicting constraints after `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you solved your issue, but just to provide a little color on Auto Layout: I had the same requirement to "collapse" a view that can't meet it's intrinsic content size and tried the same zero-width constraint technique. The problem with that technique is described in this portion of the [Auto Layout documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint):

> After solving for the required constraints, Auto Layout tries to solve all the optional constraints in priority order from highest to lowest. If it cannot solve for an optional constraint, it tries to come as close as possible to the desired result, and then moves on to the next constraint.

Apparently Auto Layout would rather get *close* to satisfying a constraint than satisfy a lower priority constraint. That's a bit weird to me because if I want a width to be `>= 100` then it's not clear that 90 is "better" than 80. That said, I'm sure doing it this way results in more intuitive behavior in the vast majority of cases.

Unfortunately, this makes it impossible to use lower priority constraints as "fall-back" constraints for cases where higher priority constraints can't be satisfied. I suppose Apple's view is that the only purpose of lower priority constraints is to make the layout more specific when the higher priority constraints result in an *under* constrained layout.